# Can't join collections with ids in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, match

I am trying to get all requests of a user from the request collection based on request status. I am trying to lookup the collection but it doesn't work. Is there any solution to work it out.

Here is my code:

```
Users.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'requests',
                let: {userId: '$userId', status: '$status'},
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $expr: { 
                               $and: [
                                 { $eq: ['$_id', '$$userId'] },
                                 { $eq: ['$$status', 1] }
                               ]
                            },
                        }
                    }
                ],
                as: 'requests'
            }
        }
    ]).exec()
```

I think `{ $eq: ['$_id', '$$userId'] }` is not working. I tried using `$toObjectId` but still same result.

Here is test data for users:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f1c0112ad207a13308a3fea"
    },
    "createDate": {
        "$date": "2020-07-25T09:52:58.678Z"
    },
    "userRole": 10,
    "status": 1,
    "fullName": "Test Name",
    "email": "test.name@mailinator.com",
    "password": "$2b$10$HQN//qFTQKW8tBnf7G0OV.Uta0zNbxd1hPlGVwvLp5CVIf49Y5PNW",
    "__v": 0,
    "profileImage": "1595957619296.jpg"
}
```

And test request data:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f2178c578153018ca5d79e8"
    },
    "request": "This is a demo request.",
    "userId": {
        "$oid": "5f1c0112ad207a13308a3fea"
    },
    "createDate": {
        "$date": "2020-07-28T18:30:00.000Z"
    },
    "status": 1
}
```

Comment: can you add your example data of both collection in your question.

Comment: @turivishal I have added test data to the question. Thanks!

Comment: An alternative to do this: [play link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3AMpdgdBOr2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few fixes in your query,

- `$match` your user document `status` is 1, if you don't want then your can exclude,

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      status: 1
    }
  },
```

- `$lookup` with requests
- `let` `userId` it is from user collection so add user collection `_id` so its corrected,
- no need to create `status` variable because we already checked condition for in above

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "requests",
      let: {
        userId: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
```

- `$eq` check first is requests collection `$userId` and second is that we have created variable above in `let` and use `$$userId` because its reference to main collection users `let` variables

```
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$userId",
                    "$$userId"
                  ]
                },
```

- second `$eq` check `$status` is 1 in requests collection, and you did it in user collection we we have already used in above $match condition

```
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$status",
                    1
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "requests"
    }
  }
])
```

Have divided in parts for explanation purpose you can merge it as they are in sequence,

Working Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/THU6HeyqMN4